# A simpler proof of an important statement in the book "Galois Theory" by Ian Stewart

Tags: galois-theory

Reading the book "Galois Theory" (3rd ed.) by Ian Stewart, I try for better understanding and possible
future formalization to rewrite  Stewart's proof of a very important Lemma 15.7

*If $K$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ and $L:K$
is normal and radical then $\Gamma(L:K)$ is soluble*

in a more structured way (see "Structuring Mathematical Proofs" by Uri Leron and 
"How to Write a 21st Century Proof" by Leslie Lamport, available for free via Google, as well as the book).

Let us remind some definitions (all fields here are subfields of $\mathbb{C}$).

**Definition 1**. A simple radical extension is a field extension $L:K$, if there exist $n,a$ such that $n \in \mathbb{N}, a \in \mathbb{C}, a \notin K,
a^n \in K, L = K(a)$.

**Definition 2**. A prime simple radical extension is a simple radical extension $L:K$, if  $n$ in Definition 1 is a prime number.

**Lemma 1**. If $K(a):K$ is a normal prime simple radical extension, where $a^p \in K$then $L$ contains all $pth$ roots of unity.
  A proof of Lemma 1 can be extracted from Stewart's proof of Lemma 15.7 (the lines 7-12 of the proof).

**Lemma 2**. If $L:K$ is a normal prime simple radical extension, then $\Gamma(L:K)$ is abelian.   Follows from Lemma 15.5 in the book and Lemma 1.

**Lemma 3**. For any radical extension $L:K$, there exists a sequence of subfields

$K = M_{0} \subset M_{1} \subset M_{2} \ldots \subset M_{n} = L$  where $n \geq 0$

such that $M_i : M_{i-1}$ is a prime simple radical extension $(i=1,2,\ldots,n)$.
It is Proposition 8.9 in the book.

Now a simpler proof of Lemma 15.7 can be written as follows:

By Lemma 3, there exists a sequence of subfields

$K = M_{0} \subset M_{1} \subset M_{2} \ldots \subset M_{n} = L$  where $n \geq 0$

such that $M_{i} : M_{i-1}$ is a prime simple radical extension, $i=1,2, \ldots, n$ .

Now proceed by induction on $n$.

If $n=0$ then $L=K$ and $\Gamma(K:K)$ is a trivial group which is abelian and therefore solvable.

If $n>0$ then $K \subset N  \subset L$, where $N = M_{n-1}$.

The extension $L:N$ is normal (because $L:K$ is normal and $N$ is an intermediate field).

By Theorem 12.4(4), $\Gamma(L:N)$ is normal in $\Gamma(L:K)$.

By Theorem 12.4(5), $\Gamma(N:K) \cong \Gamma(L:K) / \Gamma(L:N)$.

By induction, $\Gamma(N:K)$ is soluble.

By Lemma 2, $\Gamma(L:N)$ is abelian and therefore soluble.

Therefore, by Theorem 14.4(3) $\Gamma(L:K)$ is soluble.

End of proof of Lemma 15.7.

Is this proof correct?

Any comments are welcome.

Comment: I have nothing to contribute to the question, but I just wanted to thank you for posting those two papers, which I have never seen before and am enjoying immensely. (Here are links, for the benefit of others: [Leron](http://courses.daiict.ac.in/pluginfile.php/18938/mod_resource/content/4/structuring%20mathematical%20proofs_leron_amm.pdf) and [Lamport](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/proof.pdf))

Answer (score 2):

Both the proof in the book and your proof seem to me pretty messy, involved and long, but this could be due to the fact that neither you nor Stewart assume some slightly deeper knowledge of what soluble groups are but the very definition, and also because some facts about automorphism of fields extensions are lacking (I can't tell: I haven't read the book).

I'd go as follows, using your notation:

By lemma $\;3\;$ there exists a sequence of fields $\;K=:M_0\subset M_1\subset\ldots\subset M_n:=L\;$ , s.t. $\; M_i:M_{i-1}\;$ is a a prime simple radical extension.

But by lemma $\;2\;$ it then follows that $\;\Gamma (M_i:M_{i-1})\;$ is abelian. Thus, there exists in $\;\Gamma (L:K)\;$ a subnormal series of abelian groups, which is *exactly* the definition of soluble group. $\;{}{}$ Q.E.D.

More surprising to me is that the above **is** the definition of soluble group in Stewart's book (because there is another usual, equivalent one by means of the derived series and stuff), so I'm not sure why the proof comes up so long and messy, though I can understand the use of induction but only to make sure the argument about the abelian series is completely formal.

Comment: Your "proof" is too short - there is no reference to Galois correspondence.

Comment: @user17374 Of course there is: where do you think the abelian series come from?!

Comment: I'm afraid that both our "proofs" are incorrect: they silently presupppose that any prime simple radical extension is a normal extension.

Comment: Anyway, could you provide a reference in the literature to your (or similar to yours) proof?

Comment: @user17374 First, I presuppose nothing: it is **given** the extension is normal!...and radical, and then I go by the book. But even if it isn't given, taking the normal closure of the prime radical extension still gives us, as shown above, a soluble automorphism group, and now the claim follows from the fact that subgroups and factor groups of a soluble group are soluble themselves. Unless some mistake is shown specifically, I think my proof is perfectly kosher. Second, no: I know of no reference for a proof like mine of this result.

Comment: It is given that  $L:K$ is normal. but not $M_{i} : M_{i-1}$. Take $M_{0} = \mathbb{Q}, M_{1} = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$.  $M_{1} : M_{0}$ is a prime simple radical extension, but not normal extension.

Comment: Your (and mine) mistake is that you use Lemma 2, without proving before that $M_i : M_{i-1}$ is a normal extension.

Comment: You wrote "the normal closure of the prime radical extension still gives us, as shown above, a soluble automorphism group, and now the claim follows from the fact that subgroups and factor groups of a soluble group are soluble themselves".  SO PLEASE EDIT YOUR PROOF.

Comment: @user17374 No, I won't edit my proof: that's for you, the asker, to complete. And why would I want or need to prove that $\;M_i:M_{i-1}\;$ is normal? First, this may not be true but it doesn't affect the proof: a subgroup of a soluble group is soluble, wheteher the subgroup is normal or not. All I need is *the big extension* to be normal to apply lemma 2, not that the middle subextensions are normal. I think *your* mistake is either not understanding this part of fields extensions or else not knowing the basic of soluble groups. Of course, needless to add, I *still* could be wrong. :)